# Google Sheets API : Formatting select ranges differently within the same batchUpdate request array

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am struggling to format multiple sections of the sheet on the same request array using the batch update in the google sheets API.

I've been able to update the formatting successfully, **but only the last entry in the request array updates** (using the repeatCell format).

Additionally, I want to use this summation "=SUM(B4:B12)" and could not get it.

```
    requestFormatBody = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                    "endColumnIndex": 3,
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "backgroundColor": {
                            "red": 0.0,
                            "green": 0.0,
                            "blue": 0.0,
                        },
                        "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
                        "textFormat": {
                            "foregroundColor": {
                                "red": 1.0,
                                "green": 1.0,
                                "blue": 1.0,
                            },
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "bold": True,
                        },
                    }
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment)",
            },
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "startRowIndex": 2,
                    "endRowIndex": 3,
                    "endColumnIndex": 3,
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "backgroundColor": {
                            "red": 255 / 255,
                            "green": 255 / 255,
                            "blue": 204 / 255,
                        },
                        "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
                        "textFormat": {
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "bold": True,
                        },
                    }
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment)",
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

I was able to create the sheets and assign values as needed, stuck on formatting.
Thanks

Edit: Adding reference pictures
Essentially I want these in the same "requests" array sent in the **body** of **spreadsheets().batchUpdate()**.
When using as shown above I only get the last "repeatCell" block, when I only do one of the "repeatCell"'s I can get either. I would like both at once though. Is this possible?

(Don't have enough points to embed, sorry for the links)

[image: Formatting 1]

[image: Formatting 2]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: added some reference pictures, thanks for looking into it

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. About your added 2 images of "Formatting 1" and "Formatting 2", which is the sample input and output situation? I couldn't understand your sample input and output situations you expect from your updated question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: no worries, this sheet is a creation of the program itself. This is happening before the formatting where the sheet is created in the proper directory. Both of the attached images are outputs, just different results of  the request body. The input would be the sheet without formatting. I'm pretty sure there is no way to batch the "repeatCell" in the same request array in the way I'm trying to use it. I think I'm just going to have to be aware of the quota limit for writes for sheets API (60/min) and delay it when necessary

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a modified request body as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the output situations of your 2 images by one API call.

In this case, how about the following modification?

When I saw your showing request body, it is as follows.

```
{
   "requests":[
      {
         "repeatCell":{,,,},
         "repeatCell":{,,,}
      }
   ]
}
```

In this case, 2 properties of `repeatCell` are existing. By this, one of them is used. In this case, it is required to be the following object.

```
{
   "requests":[
      {"repeatCell":{,,,}},
      {"repeatCell":{,,,}}
   ]
}
```

By this, 2 requests of `repeatCell` are run.

When this is reflected in your showing request body, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified request body:

```py
requestFormatBody = {
   "requests":[
      {
         "repeatCell":{
            "range":{
               "endRowIndex":1,
               "endColumnIndex":3
            },
            "cell":{
               "userEnteredFormat":{
                  "backgroundColor":{
                     "red":0.0,
                     "green":0.0,
                     "blue":0.0
                  },
                  "horizontalAlignment":"CENTER",
                  "textFormat":{
                     "foregroundColor":{
                        "red":1.0,
                        "green":1.0,
                        "blue":1.0
                     },
                     "fontSize":12,
                     "bold":True
                  }
               }
            },
            "fields":"userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment)"
         }
      },
      {
         "repeatCell":{
            "range":{
               "startRowIndex":2,
               "endRowIndex":3,
               "endColumnIndex":3
            },
            "cell":{
               "userEnteredFormat":{
                  "backgroundColor":{
                     "red":255 / 255,
                     "green":255 / 255,
                     "blue":204 / 255
                  },
                  "horizontalAlignment":"CENTER",
                  "textFormat":{
                     "fontSize":12,
                     "bold":True
                  }
               }
            },
            "fields":"userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment)"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

- In your showing request body, `sheetId` is not used. So, 1st sheet is used. If you want to use other sheet, please add `sheetId` in the range.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)